# mariadb replication - Error on renaming column name

Tags: mysql, mariadb

On master I renamed a column. To my surprise, renaming a column on master breaks mariadb replication. This is the error shown using `show slave status\G;`

```
 Last_Error: Error 'Error on rename of './MY_DATABASE/#sql-1e23_13' to './MY_DATABASE/ON_SITE_TRACKING' (errno: 150)' on query. Default database: 'MY_DATABASE'. Query: 'ALTER TABLE `ON_SITE_TRACKING` CHANGE `user_agent_id` `on_user_agent_id` INT(11)
 UNSIGNED
 NULL
 DEFAULT NULL'
```

What is the usual workaround? What is the reason for such implementation? What kind of changes to the master scheme will also break replication?

Master mariadb version:

```
Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.4.20-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1
```

Slave mariadb version:

```
Ver 15.1 Distrib 5.5.68-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1
```

Comment: Errno 150 is a foreign key error, it has nothing to do with renaming columns. I suspect you changed the data type of your column as well as the name, and it is not compatible with the column it references (or is referenced by).

Comment: Also you should not replicate from a newer MariaDB version to an older version. See https://mariadb.com/kb/en/replication-overview/#cross-version-replication-compatibility. MariaDB 5.5 is not even listed, because it was past its end-of-life in April 2020.

Comment: spot on with both comments